# array_udiff() filter with 2 keys

Tags: php, arrays

i need a function to find changes in the 'right' key for the same user_id

In my example i have 2 arrays:

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'user_id' => '367',
        'right' => 'RW',
    ),
    array(
        'user_id' => '48',
        'right' => 'RWD',
    )
);
$b = array(
    array(
        'user_id' => '57',
        'right' => 'RWD',
    ),
    array(
        'user_id' => '367',
        'right' => 'RWD',
    )
);
$result = array_udiff($a, $b, 'myFunc');
$result2 = array_udiff($b, $a, 'myFunc');
```

Now i must receive:

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'user_id' => '367',
        'right' => 'RW',
    )
)
$result2 =  array(
    array(
        'user_id' => '367',
        'right' => 'RWD',
    )
)
```

I try a lot but i did not get the correct function.

Can anyone help me please.

Edit:

I try it with:

```
function myFunc($a, $b){
    if($a['user_id'] == $b['user_id']){
        return strcmp($a['right'], $b['right']);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is empty. Better to explain is it with foreach:

```
function myFunc($a, $b){
 $output = array();
 foreach($a as $_a){
  foreach($b as $_b){
   if($_a['user_id'] == $_b['user_id']){
    if($_a['right'] != $_b['right']){
     $output[] = $_a;
     break;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return $output;
}
```

Comment: 1. Please show the code of your function 2. Why do you call `array_udiff()` twice ? 3. What logic is behind your expected output? 4. And what is your current output?

Comment: I print my function above.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc($a, $b)
{
    if($a['right'] < $b['right'])
        return -1;
    else if($a['right'] > $b['right'])
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Do you mean this ?

Comment: Please don't ask OP questions as answers. Use comments for clarification

Comment: @Niek van der Steen There is missing the check if the user_id is the same.